# Angle between two curves

Tags: calculus, functions, curves

If two curves intersect at two or more points, what will we consider the angle between the two curves; or will the angle be individually defined for the points?

Answer (score 0):

The angle at the point of intersection between two curves is given by the arc-cosine of the dot product of the unit tangent vectors of the two curves at the point of intersection. This method works no matter how many intersection points the curves have.

Comment: So it will be considered individually for each of the points, not like the smallest angle between them or something?

Comment: Each intersection point will have an angle of intersection.